The text and the icon is not being responsive (Angular and scss)
img01
This is the problem. When I add more pax, the text is going under the icon.
Here is the code:
<div class="input-element pax-container trip-panel-fields">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="identityIcon"></ng-container>
          <ey-pax-input-cont class="input"
            formControlName="passengers"
            [config]="config.paxInputContConfig"
            [selectedAirports$]="selectedAirports$"
            (registerInteraction)="registerSubformInteraction($event)">
          </ey-pax-input-cont>
        </div>

ey-pax-input-pres:
<div class="form-field-container">
  <mat-form-field
    class="block full-width"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-form-field-invalid': hasDangerDisplayInput()}">
    <input
      matInput
      readonly
      eyInputPopover
      [component]="extendablePaxForm"
      [value]="translations.passengersWithCount | o3rTranslate:{passengerCount: paxFormGroup.value | travelersDescription$}"
      [placeholder]="translations.passengers | o3rTranslate"
      class="input-display"
      (open)="onExpand()"
      (cancel)="onCancel()"
      (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"/>
    <mat-icon matSuffix class="des-icon-chevron-down"></mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

style file for this:
.pax-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        &.trip-panel-fields {
          @include for-size(md-down) {
            align-items: baseline;
          }

          .pax-icon {
            @include for-size(md-up) {
              align-self: center;
              margin-left: .5rem;
            }

            position: relative;
            top: .1875rem;

            @include for-size(md-down) {
              img {
                width: 8px;
                height: 10px;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        .mat-mdc-input-element {
          // @include for-size(md-up) {
          //   max-width: 4.6875rem;
          // }
          max-width: 3.75rem;
          // width: auto;
          // flex-grow: 1;
          // flex-shrink: 1;
        }

        // .mat-icon {
        //   @include for-size(md-up) {
        //     width: 1rem;
        //   }
        // }
      }

Please help me I'm stuck on this for hourssss
I tried wrapping it in flex (display: flex). I don't want the width to be fixed. It should automatically move the icon as the text goes bigger an smaller. I tried flex-grow and flex shrink. Did not work :(
Here is extra code:


@import './search-panel.style.theme';
@import 'responsive';

.search-select-panel {
  .trip-type-panel {
    .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
      font-size: 1.125rem;
    }

    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    min-width: max-content !important;
  }

  .mat-mdc-option {
    @include ey-body-3;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.125rem;

    .trip-icon-width {
      width: 1.25rem;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: $light-grey-2;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }

    &:not(.mat-mdc-option-multiple) {
      height: 2.5rem;
      padding-right: 2.5rem;
      padding-left: 0;

      &.mat-active {
        background: none !important;
      }

      &::after {
        border-bottom: none !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

ey-search-panel {
  @include for-size(sm-up) {
    .miles-toggle-container {
      ey-miles-toggle-pres {
        .miles-toggle-panel {
          border-bottom: $miles-toggle-pres-border-color;
          border-bottom-style: groove;
          border-bottom-width: $miles-toggle-pres-border-bottom-width;
          margin: 0 0 1rem;
        }

        .miles-toggle-panel-information,
        .miles-toggle-panel-description {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row-reverse;
        }

        .miles-toggle-label {
          padding: .125rem .5rem 0 0;

          [dir='rtl'] & {
            padding: .125rem 0 0 .5rem;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .search-panel {
    @include for-size(lg-up) {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;

      &.is-not-modifying {
        margin: 4rem auto;
      }
    }

    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    .card {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .mat-divider,
    .flight-status-divider {
      opacity: 1;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .button-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      padding: 1rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    }

    .divider-padding {
      padding: 0 2rem;
    }

    .button-element {
      @include for-size(md-up) {
        width: 48%;
      }

      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .flight-status-button {
      text-align: center;
      min-height: 3.2rem;
      background-color: $light-grey-3;
      color: $charcoal;
      border: 0;
    }

    .flight-icon {
      @include for-size(sm-down) {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      font-size: 1.3rem;
      color: $accent-500;
    }

    .trip-panel {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;

      @include for-size(xs-up) {
        column-gap: .875rem;
      }

      @include for-size(sm-down) {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        column-gap: .25rem;
      }

      .mat-mdc-form-field {
        width: 100%;
        .mat-mdc-select-value .mat-mdc-select-value-text {
          @include ey-body-3;

          @include for-size(md-up) {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
          }

          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: .875rem;
        }
      }

      ey-cabin-class-selection-pres {
        .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
          @include for-size(md-down) {
            width: max-content;
          }
        }
      }

      .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        column-gap: .25rem;
        padding: .5rem 0;
        border-top: none;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: unset;

        .mat-mdc-select-value {
          margin-right: .375rem;
        }

        .mat-mdc-select-panel {
          .mat-mdc-option {
            @include ey-body-3;
            font-weight: 300;
          }

        }

        .mat-mdc-input-element {
          @include ey-body-3;

          @include for-size(md-up) {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
          }

          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: .875rem;
          max-width: 3.8rem;
        }


        &>span {
          display: inline-flex;
          align-items: center;
        }
      }

      .pax-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        &.trip-panel-fields {
          @include for-size(md-down) {
            align-items: baseline;
          }

          .pax-icon {
            @include for-size(md-up) {
              align-self: center;
              margin: 0 .25rem 0 .5rem;
              top: .125rem;
            }

            position: relative;

            @include for-size(sm-down) {
              img {
                width: 8px;
                height: 10px;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        .mat-mdc-input-element {
          // @include for-size(md-up) {
          //   max-width: 4.6875rem;
          // }
          max-width: 3.75rem;
          // width: auto;
          // flex-grow: 1;
          // flex-shrink: 1;
        }

        // .mat-icon {
        //   @include for-size(md-up) {
        //     width: 1rem;
        //   }
        // }
      }

      .cabin-container {
        .mat-mdc-input-element {
          @include ey-body-3;

          @include for-size(md-up) {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            max-width: 4.8125rem;
          }

          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: .875rem;
          max-width: 3.75rem;
          text-align: center;

          &.short {
            max-width: 3rem;
          }
        }

        .mat-icon {
          @include for-size(md-down) {
            width: 1rem;
          }
        }

        .mat-mdc-form-field-icon-suffix {
          .mat-icon {
            font-size: .875rem;
            margin-top: -.375rem;
            width: .875rem;
            height: .875rem;
          }
        }

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .trip-panel-fields {
        .mat-form-field-appearance-fill {
          .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
            padding: 0 .25rem !important;
            background-color: $white;

            .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
              border: 0;
              padding-left: .0625rem;
              padding-right: .25rem;
              column-gap: 0;

              [dir='rtl'] & {
                padding-left: .25rem;
                padding-right: .0625rem;
              }
            }
          }

          .mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
            background-color: $white !important;
          }
        }

        .mat-mdc-select-arrow {
          @include for-size(md-up) {
            font-size: 1rem;
          }

          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          font-size: .875rem;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        &.trip-type {
          .mat-mdc-select-arrow-wrapper{
            margin-top: .125rem;
          }

          .mat-mdc-input-element {
            @include for-size(md-down) {
              max-width: 3.8125rem;
            }
          }
        }

        .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper,
        .mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
          &:hover {
            background: unset !important;
            border-radius: 1.5rem;
          }
        }

        &:hover {
          background-color: $light-grey-3;
          border-radius: 1.5rem;
        }

        @include for-size(md-down) {
          margin-top:-.1875rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .search-section {
    padding: 2rem;
  }

  .is-modifying {
    ey-card>.card {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }

  .search-panel-header {
    height: 4.5rem;
  }

  .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-line-ripple::before {
    border: none;
  }

  ey-search-form-cont,
  ey-multi-city-search-cont ey-multi-city-search-pres {
    mat-label,
    input.mat-mdc-input-element {
      @include ey-body-3;
      line-height: 1rem !important;
      font-weight: 300 !important;
      color: $charcoal !important;
      margin-top: -.75rem;
      margin-bottom: .5rem;
    }
    .mdc-notched-outline {
      color: $charcoal !important;
    }

    .mdc-notched-outline {
      .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
      .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
      .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
        border-width: .0625rem !important;
        color: $link-blue;
      }
    }

    .mat-form-field-appearance-outline {
      .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
        height: 2.5rem;
      }

      .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
        height: 2.5rem;
        padding: 0;

        input {
          [dir='rtl'] & {
            text-align: right;
          }
        }
      }

      .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
        border-radius: .5rem 0 0 .5rem !important;
        border-right-style: none;

        [dir='rtl'] & {
          border-right-style: solid;
          border-radius: 0 .5rem .5rem 0 !important;
        }
      }

      .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
        border-radius: 0 .5rem .5rem 0 !important;
        border-left-style: none;
        flex-grow: 1;

        [dir='rtl'] & {
          border-left-style: solid;
          border-radius: .5rem 0 0 .5rem !important;
        }
      }
    }

    .input-row .search-form-submit-button {
      @include ey-display-5;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
<div class="search-panel" [ngClass]="isModifyingSearch ? 'is-modifying' : 'is-not-modifying'">
  <ey-card class="card top-padding">

    <ng-container content *ngIf="displayRecentCartsAtTheTop">
      <div class="recent-carts-top">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recentCart"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    <div content [ngClass]="{'search-section': !isModifyingSearch}">
      <ey-miles-toggle-cont *ngIf="!isModifyingSearch" class="miles-toggle-container"></ey-miles-toggle-cont>
      <!-- Trip Data Selection -->
      <form [formGroup]="tripDataForm" class="trip-panel">
        <!-- Trip Type -->
        <div class="trip-type trip-panel-fields">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tripIcon"></ng-container>
            <mat-select  panelClass="trip-type-panel" [(value)]="activeTripType" (selectionChange)="selectTripType($event.value)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let tripType of config.tripTypes; index as i; trackBy: trackById" [value]="tripType">
                <span class="trip-icon-width">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="activeTripType === tripType">
                    <i [ngClass]="'validate' | icon"></i>
                  </ng-container>
                </span>
                  {{translations.tripType | o3rTranslate:{tripType: tripType} }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <!-- Passengers -->
        <div class="input-element pax-container trip-panel-fields">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="identityIcon"></ng-container>
          <ey-pax-input-cont class="input"
            formControlName="passengers"
            [config]="config.paxInputContConfig"
            [selectedAirports$]="selectedAirports$"
            (registerInteraction)="registerSubformInteraction($event)">
          </ey-pax-input-cont>
        </div>
        <!-- Cabin -->
        <div class="cabin-container trip-panel-fields" >
          <ey-cabin-class-selection-pres
            class="input"
            formControlName="cabinClass"
            [cabinClassList]="getCabinClassList()"
            [config]="config.cabinClassConfig"
            (registerInteraction)="registerSubformInteraction($event)">
            </ey-cabin-class-selection-pres>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="activeTripType === 'complex' ? complex : simple; context: {tripType: activeTripType}"></ng-container>
    </div>

    <ng-container content *ngIf="!displayRecentCartsAtTheTop">
      <div class="recent-carts-bottom">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recentCart"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!--Flight status button-->
    <div content *ngIf="enableFlightStatus">
      <div class="divider-padding">
        <mat-divider class="flight-status-divider"></mat-divider>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <div class="button-element">
          <button mat-flat-button class="button-unstyled flight-status-button" (click)="flightStatusClick.emit()">
            <mat-icon class="flight-icon" fontIcon="des-icon-flight-departure"></mat-icon>
            {{ translations.flightStatus | o3rTranslate }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Search form -->
    <ng-template #simple let-tripType="tripType">
      <ey-search-form-cont content
        class="search-form"
        [isActiveTripType]="activeTripType === tripType"
        [config]="config.searchFormContConfig"
        [tripType]="tripType"
        [selectedCabinAndGuest]="selectedCabinAndGuest"
        [isModifyingSearch]="isModifyingSearch"
        (search)="onSearch()"
        (airportSelected)="getAirportData($event)">
      </ey-search-form-cont>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #complex>
      <ey-multi-city-search-cont
        [isActiveTripType]="activeTripType === 'complex'"
        [config]="config.multiCitySearchContConfig"
        [isModifyingSearch]="isModifyingSearch"
        [selectedCabinAndGuest]="selectedCabinAndGuest"
        (search)="onSearch()">
      </ey-multi-city-search-cont>
    </ng-template>

    <!--Recent cart-->
    <ng-template #recentCart>
      <ey-recent-carts-cont
        *ngIf="!isModifyingSearch"
        [config]="config.recentCartsContConfig"
        [displayDivider]="displayRecentCartsAtTheTop"
        (resumeBookingFromCart)="onResumeBookingFromCart()">
      </ey-recent-carts-cont>
    </ng-template>
  </ey-card>
</div>

<ng-template #tripIcon>
  <span *ngIf="activeTripType === 'oneway' || activeTripType === 'complex'">
    <img [ngSrc]="config.onewayTripImagePath | o3rDynamicContent" alt="" width="16" height="16" />
  </span>
  <span
    *ngIf="activeTripType === 'roundtrip'">
    <img [ngSrc]="config.roundTripImagePath | o3rDynamicContent" alt="" width="13" height="10" />
  </span>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #identityIcon>
  <span class="pax-icon">
    <img [ngSrc]="config.identityIcon | o3rDynamicContent" alt="" width="10" height="13" />
  </span>
</ng-template>




it will be difficult to figure out the problem without a reproducible code. can you provide the html and css with static data to reproduce the issue?

I have added additional code, Please do help me

you have .mat-mdc-input-element {max-width: 3.75rem;}.

If I set that as auto or take it off, it will expand, I don't want it to take up the entire space
